# Identitical Strings that do not match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building a sortable word quiz where the user has to put the words of a sentence in the correct order. The idea is that the user drags the words from below the sentence and then the word blocks light up green or red depending on if their solution matches the answer.

I'm using jQuery and the jQuery UI sortable method. The jQuery sortable and HTML & CSS all works fine, but in my JavaScript if statement comparing the answer string with the users solution string is always **false** no matter what. The really odd thing is console.log shows the strings as being identical in every way as far as I can tell. i.e typeof show they are both of type "string" and length of both strings shows 31. I even added some code to chop white space off the ends of the strings to sanitize them. The answer is being stored in a variable called **answer** and the users solution is stored in a variable called **solution**

The demo code is live on codepen here:

https://codepen.io/codepajamas/pen/zYGMveN?editors=1111

You can open the console to see the result.

Following is the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript Code:

```html
<div class="sentence" data-answer="Henry wants to go to the store!">
  <span class="sentence-start">Henry</span>
  <ul class="words place-words"></ul>
  <span class="sentence-end">to the store!</span>
</div>
<ul class="words supply-words"><li class="word">wants </li><li class="word">go </li><li class="word">to </li></ul>
```

```js
$(function () {

var answer = $('.sentence').data('answer'); // "Henry wants to go to the store!"

$('.words').sortable({
  connectWith: '.place-words, .supply-words',
  beforeStop: function () {

    if ($('.supply-words').text() === '') {
      var sentence_start = $('.sentence-start').text(),
          placed_words = $('.place-words').text(),
          sentence_end = $('.sentence-end').text(),
          combined = sentence_start+placed_words+sentence_end,
          // get rid of line returns and white space at beginning and end of sentence
          solution = combined.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,'').trim();

      if (solution === answer) {
        console.log('correct');
        $('.place-words').removeClass('wrong').addClass('correct');
      } else {
        console.log('wrong');
        $('.place-words').removeClass('correct').addClass('wrong');
      }

    }// outer if
  }// beforeStop function
 });

$('.words, .answer').disableSelection();

}; //end document ready
```

```css
.sentence {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.words {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 135px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.word {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.correct {
  background: lime;
}

.wrong {
  background: pink;
}
```

Let me know if anyone has any questions. Any help is appreciated. I think I need a fresh set of eyes on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cool app! When I log to the console just before the comparison `console.log(solution, answer);` I see: `"Henrywants to go to the store!" "Henry wants to go to the store!"`. Can you figure it out from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic edge case of white spaces from what I can tell. I was able to get your code to work by handling white space in both the provided answer and solution.

```
// add this just before you if statement.
solution = solution.replace(/ /g, "");
answer = answer.replace(/ /g,"").trim();
```

But it looks like you are missing the space on your first word. "wants "

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not wild about this solution because it jams words together and can introduce false positives, claiming `"foo bar"` and `"fo obar"` are the same. Contrived example, but it can happen. `combined = sentence_start + " " + placed_words + sentence_end` just adds in the missing space and seems a little less invasive. Either way, the `trim` call isn't necessary since you already stripped out all of the spaces.

Comment: Good point if I simply add a space in the html after "Henry" and make it "Henry " instead it works. without needing trim(). I will have to think of a way to be careful of the quiz creator adding in or leaving out spaces when they write the sentence. I'll be using PHP form to allow a teacher to write their own sentence and answer so trim should come in handy for that though. Thanks everyone!